# executing the results of an expression in powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, aws-sdk

I have seen a few ways that I am supposed to be able to execute a string a command (equivalent to eval in *nix) and this should work but I get

```
& : The term 'docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr get-login | %{ -replace \'-e
none\', ''}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker run -it ...'-e none\', ''}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

the command on it's own does what I need - it GETS the aws loging for ECR which I must then invoke - it's fantastically dumb but that's aws.

Here is what I ran:

```
& "docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr
 get-login | %{$_ -replace \'-e none\', ''}"
```

Putting the full docker path in the command doesn't help

```
& : The term ''C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe' run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev
--region us-east-1 ecr get-login | %{ -replace \'-e none\', ''}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe' run -it  ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ('C:\Program Fil...'-e none\', ''}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am unfamiliar with how powershell handles this scenario - some guidance would be great.

**UPDATE**

The below command produces ANOTHER command which must then be executed in order to log into AWS ECR (their docker container registry). I am trying to just 1-line it so people can C&P it. Ideally substituting my user home for theirs

```
docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr get-login | %{ -replace \'-e
none\', ''}
```

example output from above (really long and hence why I want to 1-line it):

```
docker login -u AWS -p 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  https://882038671278.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: The `&` operator executes the next token as a command. You don't need it unless the command path or name contains whitespace. Remove your quoting and just run the command.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I added some details to help better understand the problem. The command I am running actually produces ANOTHER command that is the final one to be run. It's an aws hack-glory

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827360/ and my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, got it:

```
Invoke-Expression  ($(docker run -it --rm -v $home\.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --profile dev --region us-east-1 | %{$_ -replace "https://", ""}))
```

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression`. The command name followed by parameters is all you need. Just like if you were running a command from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your command ends because you have a line break in it and that's not allowed at this point. A reliable way to run extermal command would be something like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe' -ArgumentList 'run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr'
```

What is `get-login`? It is not a standard Powershell cmdlet.

Comment: `get-login` is an aws cli argument and it's an ugly one. You have to ask aws for the full command you would need to execute to login to ecr (their container registry) but the command you get back is actually wrong and you need to strip something out. Once you have that stripped command you need to execute it

Comment: `Start-Process` is not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to try so hard. PowerShell can run a command line (it is a shell, after all). This is all you need to do:

```
docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr
```

If the command's path or name contains spaces, then you can quote the command name and use the `&` operator; e.g.:

```
& "C:\Program Files\docker\docker" -it --rm -v ...
```

You made a common mistake (quoting the entire command string). But if `docker` is available in the current path as a command, you can just run it.

If the command outputs a `docker` command line that you want to run, you can do this:

```
docker run -it --rm -v C:/Users/cbongiorno/.aws:/root/.aws garland/aws-cli-docker aws --profile dev --region us-east-1 ecr | ForEach-Object {
  & docker (($_ -replace '^docker ','') -split ' ')
}
```

The first line creates a `docker` command line and writes it to stdout. Inside `ForEach-Object`, we run `docker` again with the arguments from stdout. You can put the `ForEach-Object { ... }` on the same line as the command if you want.

Comment: I don't think you understand: The results of that big docker command produce a string output that represents yet another dynamically generated command with arguments. You have to execute a command to get the next command to execute. Simply can't know the next step until you execute the first

Comment: You can capture the stdout of a command by assigning to a variable. If the stdout has a single line, then the variable will be a string. If the stdout has multiple lines, then the variable will be an array.

Comment: Yes, I know that - but that isn't what I was trying to do. I was trying to get and execute both things with a 1-liner. Assigning it to a variable would add an extra line

Comment: You don't need to create a variable assignment; you can pipe to `ForEach-Object`. `$_` will contain each line from stdout.